# Legacy Database Format Migration

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all thank you for stopping by and lending a hand!

All day I have been figuring out a way to make this migration concept as fast as possible.  Basically I have many rows like this:

```
WO-ID|Line Number|Note Tran Number|Note
1    |1          |1               |... 50 char
1    |1          |2               |... 30 char
1    |1          |3               |5 char
```

At the end of all this, I need those to be brought together, a carriage return inserted between them, and then those need to be broken back into text of 60 characters, i.e:

```
WO-ID|Line Number|Note Tran Number|Note
1    |1          |1               |...50 char from line 1 and 10 char from line 2
1    |1          |2               |...20 char from tran 2 and 5 char from tran 3
```

Now, I do have multiple ways that work, but I am struggling with finding the fastest way to accomplish this.  Concatenating the strings together and adding the carriage return is fast and easy, but the process of splitting them takes a very long time the more "transactions" that the string ends up getting split into.  Right now the total length of all the notes on a dataset with 107K records is 4,244,809 characters.

All the records up to(including) 300 characters, is 3,829,351.  This finishes in about 50 seconds.  The remaining 415,458 takes a minute and 45 seconds.

This is the query I am using(I couldn't figure out a better way to do the "pages" than they way I am doing, if there is a better way I would love to hear it!  Obviously there is a faster way to insert multiple values, but I'm not too concerened with that):

```
Declare @SplitSize int;

declare @numbersTable table (number int);
insert into @numbersTable values(1);
insert into @numbersTable values(2);
insert into @numbersTable values(3);
insert into @numbersTable values(4);
insert into @numbersTable values(5);
insert into @numbersTable values(6);
insert into @numbersTable values(7);
insert into @numbersTable values(8);
insert into @numbersTable values(9);
insert into @numbersTable values(10);
insert into @numbersTable values(11);
insert into @numbersTable values(12);
insert into @numbersTable values(13);
insert into @numbersTable values(14);
insert into @numbersTable values(15);
insert into @numbersTable values(16);
insert into @numbersTable values(17);
insert into @numbersTable values(18);
insert into @numbersTable values(19);
insert into @numbersTable values(20);
insert into @numbersTable values(21);
insert into @numbersTable values(22);
insert into @numbersTable values(23);
insert into @numbersTable values(24);
insert into @numbersTable values(25);
insert into @numbersTable values(26);
insert into @numbersTable values(27);

Set @SplitSize = 60;

Select Main.wo_note_fac, main.wo_note_ro_num, main.wo_note_line_num,
        n.Number,SubString(main.note, @SplitSize*(n.Number -1) + 1, @SplitSize)
From (

        SELECT DISTINCT note2.wo_note_fac,  note2.wo_note_ro_num, note2.wo_note_line_num,
            (
                SELECT rtrim(note1.wo_note) + char(10)  AS [text()]
                FROM dbo.wonotes note1
                WHERE note1.wo_note_fac = note2.wo_note_fac and note1.wo_note_ro_num = note2.wo_note_ro_num and note1.wo_note_line_num != 0 and note2.wo_note_line_num = note1.wo_note_line_num
                ORDER BY note1.A4GLIdentity
                FOR XML PATH ('') ,TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') --need this .value thing to make sure xml characters aren't escaped
             [note]
        FROM dbo.wonotes note2

)main
Inner Join @numbersTable n On @SplitSize*n.Number < Len(main.note) + @SplitSize
```

We have clients that have 10 million+ records in that table, and I would prefer them not to be down for 2.5 hours or more!

Comment: Is there any way to create a side by side table where you push the results and then bring that online afterwards? You could add a rowversion column or last datetime changed column so you can process any changes since the secondary table was created before you do the "swap".

Comment: I agree with Igor above.  I don't think there's any way you can avoid the problem that you are reading every row, doing logic dependent on other rows and putting back into the same table.

Comment: I want to help out here... But I can't seem to understand what you are trying to do.  Your first example has all line numbers set to 1, but your second example refers to line numbers greater than 1.

Comment: @Igor no as code in the application is going to rely on the new format after the upgrade, and it needs the old format before the upgrade. We can’t be updating the table while people are making changes to it. I guess technically we could make it work in a way, but we would have to keep track of all the rows modified during the “migration” and then rerun the migration for those rows... but that seems a little messy

Comment: Are you just trying to reflow the line endings?  It seems like maybe you have lines that are 50 chars now, and you want to go to 60 chars?  (A few more sentences about what you are trying to do would help.)

Comment: @Igor unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying. If so ignore my previous comment!

Comment: @Vaccano sorry for the non-clarity!  Basically we are trying to get as close to a “modern” looking note field as possible. Best case would be a varchar(max) and all the note is in there. But, we are dealing with a legacy COBOL application and it needs the fixed length of 60 characters. So the application used to let the trans number column dictate what “line” that portion of the note belonged to. We are trying to change it so that atleast the note field dictates when the line breaks happen and not the number of the row if that makes sense!

Comment: So the "Line Number" column is not used?  Is it that WO-ID is the comment ID?  And each line in that that comment is defined by the Trans Number?  So, from a high level, you want to group by WO-ID and aggregate all the notes under that group, ordered by the Trans Number, with Carrage Returns inserted at each 60th char?

Comment: You understood correctly. That is what [`rowversion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is for. Add a new column with this data type. Then create an offline copy of the table and execute your script over it. Then you can either swap tables or do an update of the live table and the only thing you need to still do is re-run the script for records that have changed (where source.rowversion <> target.rowversion).

Comment: No. The line number column doesn’t mean note line. The note belongs to an object and that object is a line. Line number for all intents and purposes is the ID of the line. Basically in this example it should group by woid and line number, and aggregate the note column

Comment: @Igor I’ll look into that! I’ll have to see how that will work in the big picture! We have both on premise clients and hosted clients, so I will have to see how that would work for our on Prem clients. Basically a pre-update to get most of the data, then fix the rest that changed between the pre update and the update.

Comment: @JacobTurley - Are you looking to break the line mid word?  (At exactly 60 chars) or do you need to keep the words whole?

Comment: @Vaccano mid word is fine!

Comment: AS a thought, could you have the note as a varchar(max) field, and create a view for reading that splits the note output into the 60-character rows dynamically? Certainly the conversion would be faster, so the only question is if the added overhead of splitting (and re-concatenating on save) + changes to your code is excessive work to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @LaughingVergil This may be the route we are going.  Thank you for the idea!  I had thought about it before but dismissed it as I thought (because I don't have a lot of experience with views) that it would still be selecting the whole table, but it passes the filters down!  There's some other stuff we need to consider but this is looking like the best candidate so far!

Comment: Yes, the discovery that filters pass down into the view changes a lot about how useful they look.